# Issues Applying Selections to Hierarchical Datasets

Tags: filtering, dataset

I have a large dataset in the format below. I'm able to graph them as polygons easily enough, but am having trouble doing fine selections of the coordinates in `Dataset` format for further checks and processing. (I have other functions downstream that do geographic intersections that are being thrown off.) Some days I feel like I'm finally starting to understand Mathematica dataset operators, and other days I'm just confused.

```
ds = {{<|lat -> 49.275, lng -> -123.03|>, <|lat -> 49.2753, lng -> -123.03|>, <|lat -> 49.2753, lng -> -123.03|>, <|lat -> 49.275, lng -> -123.03|>, <|lat -> 49.275, lng -> -123.03|>},
{<|lat -> 49.275, lng -> -123.029|>, <|lat -> 49.2753, lng -> -123.029|>, <|lat -> 49.2753, lng -> -123.029|>, <|lat -> 49.275, lng -> -123.029|>, <|lat -> 49.275, lng -> -123.029|>}, 
{<|lat -> 49.275, lng -> -123.029|>, <|lat -> 49.275, lng -> -123.029|>, <|lat -> 49.2753, lng -> -123.029|>, <|lat -> 49.2753, lng -> -123.029|>, <|lat -> 49.275, lng -> -123.029|>}}
// Dataset
```

I have a simple check that I wanted to break out because I will probably add complexity later. I thought applying it to the dataset would be straightforward but nothing is being returned from the several configurations I've tried. I thought I was following the ["Select Elements from Dataset" doc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/SelectElementsInADataset.html) closely, but I'm still not connecting what's written there to the behaviour I'm seeing in this example. I assumed the operators would take the little mini-dataset polygon as input but I assume something else is happening instead.

```
testcoords[shape_] := shape[Min, "lat"] > 40 

testcoords[ds[[2]]]. (* true *)

ds[Select[testcoords]] 
(* returns empty Dataset *)

ds[All, Select[testcoords]] 
(* returns {} ... *)
```

How can I configure a selection operator to check each polygon?

Comment: The issue is that `testcoords` expects a `Dataset` expression, but gets a raw `List` instead. Compare e.g. `Echo[ds[2]]` with `ds[2, Echo]`. So the fix is to either make your function work with raw lists, or to wrap the data with `Dataset` beforehand, e.g. `Select[testcoords@*Dataset]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your code is doing what you think it's doing. For example:

```
ds[1, 1, "lat"]
(* Missing[KeyAbsent, lat] *)

ds[[2]][Min]
(* -123.029 *)

ds[[2]][Min, "lat"]
(* Infinity *)
```

The first one fails partly because you use `lat` in your dataset but `"lat"` in your `testcoords` and partly because I don't think `Dataset` is expecting a variable as a part specification so `ds[1, 1, lat]` also fails because `lat` has no value. I could be wrong, but I think you need to put quotes around all the `lat` and `lng` variables for them to work properly in a `Dataset`.

When you call `testcoords[ds[[2]]]`, I think that's the same as calling `ds[[2]][Min, "lat"]`. I don't really understand what that means, but it's returning `Infinity` which I can't imagine is what you want.

Your `Dataset` doesn't look like any of the examples I've come across so far where each column has its own label. I'm not familiar enough with `Dataset` to figure out how to select items with the way you've set up your `Dataset`. If you can, I would recommend working with lists directly, but if you need it to be a `Dataset` then hopefully someone else will have a better answer.

```
data = {lat, lng} /. Normal[ds]
testcoords[shape_] := Min[shape[[All, 1]]] > 40
Select[data, testcoords]
```

Where `ds` is exactly as you've defined it in your question. If you have the list of associations before it's turned into a `Dataset`, you can drop the `Normal`. I find working with lists easier when it comes to graphics as well:

```
Graphics[Polygon/@Select[data, testcoords]]
```

This doesn't show anything since many of the coordinates are identical, but it is fairly straightforward. If you want the order of latitude and longitude switched, you can just do:

```
data = {lng, lat} /. Normal[ds]
```

instead, but make sure you're testing the second coordinate with `testcoords`.

Comment: I guess I'll have to keep it as a List on the `Select` step. Thanks for the suggestions. It's filtering properly now.